# estado de los servicios en el monitoreo de ovh siempre sale en rojo

Tags: debian, iptables, vps

Tengo un vps kvm openstack en OVH. El estado de los servicios en el monitoreo de ovh siempre sale en rojo y creo que las reglas están bien configuradas en el firewall.

Reglas:

```
/sbin/iptables-A INPUT -i ens3 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i ens3 -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i ens3 -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i ens3 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i ens3 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i ens3 -p tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i ens3 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i ens3 -p tcp --dport 21 --source xx.xx.xx.xx -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i ens3 -p tcp --dport 22 --source cache.ovh.net -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i ens3 -p tcp --dport 22 --source xx.xx.xx.xx -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i ens3 -p icmp --source proxy.ovh.net -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i ens3 -p icmp --source proxy.p19.ovh.net -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i ens3 -p icmp --source proxy.rbx.ovh.net -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i ens3 -p icmp --source proxy.rbx2.ovh.net -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i ens3 -p icmp --source AAA.BBB.CCC.250 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i ens3 -p icmp --source AAA.BBB.CCC.251 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i ens3 -p icmp --source ping.ovh.net -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i ens3 -p tcp --source 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i ens3 -p udp --source 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i ens3 -j REJECT
```

---

Mensaje:

> systemctl start iptables
>
> Failed to start iptables.service: Unit iptables.service not found.
>
> ´
>   El sistema operativo es Debian 9.

Comment: Hola, estas en stackoverflow en español. Por favor traduce tu pregunta o formúlala en la versión inglesa

Answer (score 0):

Lo de:

systemctl start iptables

Failed to start iptables.service: Unit iptables.service not found.

Es normal porque iptables no es un servicio. Si no un demonio. Como no tengo mucha experiencia con OVH y su monitoring, al ser novato con OVH voy a tratar el tema del firewall con un sysadmin experimentado con el ISP OVH. Gracias,

Instale UFW y sigue pasando lo mismo...

Answer (score 0):

¡Buenas!

Yo tengo un VPS con OVH y se me solucionó autorizando unas direcciones IP que te indican ellos dentro de tu área de cliente.
Si te fijas, debajo del estado de tus servicios que te aparece ahora marcado con una X roja te pone "Monitoring SLA".
Si pulsas en los "..." que hay justo al lado y después en "Monitoring SLA de direcciones IP". Esas son las direcciones/bloques que debes autorizar.

Un saludo.